# Name of queue service bus not available

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

why when I want to select the name of my queue it is not available in the selection list? thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez7eK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYM3z.png)

Comment: What is the complete error message in the 2nd screenshot?

Comment: Could not retrieve values. Error code: 'BadRequest', Message: 'The Service Bus connection string is not of the expected format. Either there are unexpected properties within the string or the format is incorrect. Please check the string before trying again.
clientRequestId: 7ec8c945-e059-4b2b-8bdf-08e19fbea810'. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is 'DB466590-1A5B-4FA2-81E8-925350F10E91'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I have reproduced in my environment, Firstly you need to create a queue in service bus as follows:***

[image]

***Then copy the primary connection string by below process:***

[image]

***Now paste the connection string that you copied:***

[image]

***You will definitely find the queue as below:***

[image]

Comment: sorry but i can't see your screen

Comment: I have double checked from my end and can view the screenshots, please try to refresh it and check

Comment: very strange, i clean the cash and i don't see it

Comment: impossible to check it

Comment: it's ok i open it with my phone